# JavaScript: Weird behavior in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

My code looks like this:

```
someArray.forEach(x => {
// do something
console.log(‘calling api for ‘ + x);
callAnHttpApiAsync(...);
sleep(10);
});
```

The http api call is async (but I don’t use any await/async syntax) and logs something once the api sends back the response. What happens is that the forEach loop is completed and I start to see the logged responses ONLY AFTER that. I’d expect to see some responses before the loop is over (I tried increasing the amount of sleep), but no matter how long I wait or how long the loop is the responses are logged always after the loop is over. I use a sleep library of node. I see something like this:

```
calling api for 1
calling api for 2
calling api for 3
...
calling api for 10000
got response for 1
got response for 2
got response for 3
...
got response for 10000
```

I solved already this issue by using for-of and await/async (please let me know if you have better ideas), but I can’t understand the reason of this weird behavior. Why do I get the responses only after the full loop? Any ideas? Sorry for the formatting but I’m on mobile.

Comment: it's async, what makes you think it will be waited for?

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht — What? No. `forEach` is synchronous. If `callAnApiAsync` isn't then it makes no difference if it in a `for` or `forEach` loop.

Comment: Your solution is correct. At least I don't have a better idea. Using async/await with for loop will solve this problem.

Comment: @Quentin I meant that forEach will not wait for your `async` calls to complete. If you want `async` api's to complete and then run the next loop, you need to use the `for` loop. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/909.

Comment: Please start by fixing your quotes. Also, what exactly is `sleep`? Please link the library that you are using.

Comment: When you fire a synchronous job like `forEach` all other tasks, let them be synchronous or asynchronous has to wait up until it finishes. So that's what simply happening here. The `sleep` function as understand is synchrnous as mentioned in the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) **These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop!** so you are only slowing down your `.forEach()` and during that time nothing gets executed.

Comment: @Redu : Thanks. So in a forEach loop only the sync code gets executed and the async calls are just queued and will be executed after the loop. The call to sleep will just halt completely the event loop, so nothing at all happens. I’ve been programming a lot of java and this behavior is quite weird, I’d have expected the api calls to be processed in a concurrent way. Need to look into this event loop better then.

Comment: @Gismo Ranas Yes exactly. JS is single threaded. Asynchronous tasks are queued up in the event queue as functions waiting to be invoked (callbacks). They only get executed once they are invoked **and** the synchronous code that's currently being executed at that moment completes. I know it sounds ugly but there is in fact a huge amount of free time on the thread for the event queue. Any CPU intensive jobs should be passed over to [workers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) which are asynchronously (but concurrently according to the main thread) run on separate CPU threads.

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure: I don't really know node.js, only client-side javascript, but I think the explanation works here as well.

The crux of the issue is that "asynchronous" doesn't mean "parallel". When you call an asynchronous operation, it gets placed in a queue. When the JSVM finishes executing the code it's currently running (which in this case is the code containing your `forEach`), then and only then does it take the first operation in the async queue and execute it; then, when that finishes, it runs the one after that, and so on. I.e. no matter how many async jobs you start, only one will ever run at a time.