# Iterating through : Reader.OnLoad

Tags: javascript, for-loop, base64, orientation, onload

I think I'm quite close to resolving this for myself but I just can't get the last part working so was hoping for a little bit of help. I've spent the last couple of weeks trying to write this, using all sorts of resources from StackOverflow and although I've learned a fair bit in the process, I'm now at the stage of just wanting to get it working (frustrated!)

When you run the script, it just gives a button which accepts multiple files to be selected. For each file selected, all I really need to get is the Base64 image data. I've managed to do this but since found out when getting this data, some of my images were upside down!

So.. I went off again, done some more research and put in a couple of functions which; a) detect if the image orientation needed adjusting..  and b) to adjust it as necessary. You'll see references to these 2 functions although I haven't included them. Seems to work, not fully tested yet because of the problem I have right now.

So I added a few alert commands into this so I could see the flow, I run the script and it shows me the first arrayCounter. It then gives the name of the file I'm dealing with (just so I know), then it should jump into the fileRead.onload function and start doing some more processing. At this stage, if I have say 5 files selected, it seems to go through the for loop 5 times but only ever processes the last file in the array? hope that makes sense.

I don't quite understand why it's only processing the last one. Well, I kinda do understand but I can't fix it. I know it's got something to do with asyncronous running of the fileRead.onload and I've attempted to make it work by using a closure.

I was hoping it would alert me with something like:

arrayCounter: 0  **>**  filename: myFile.jpg  **>**  inside onload.. myFile.jpg  **>**  etc

But it seems to be acting like this instead:

arrayCounter: 0  **>**  filename: myFile1.jpg  **>**  arrayCounter: 1  **>**  filename: myFile2.jpg etc

Untill it gets to the 5th file, then it goes into the section where it checks orientation of the files but only ever does the last one. I can't get it running on each file, maybe I need seperate instances of the fileRead.onload instance?

I hope that makes sense. It doesn't flow in the order I'd expect it too.
What am I doing wrong!

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

  var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
  var arrayCounter = 0;
  var imageList = [];

  for (arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < filesSelected.length; arrayCounter++) {

    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[arrayCounter];
    alert("arrayCounter: " + arrayCounter);

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    alert("filename: " + fileToLoad.name);

    fileReader.onload = (function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      return function(e) {

        alert("inside onload...  " + fileToLoad.name);

        var srcData = e.target.result; // base64 data
        alert(srcData);

        alert("now we check orientation... arrayCounter: " + arrayCounter);
        getOrientation(fileToLoad, function(orientation) {
          if (orientation == 1) {
            imageList.push(srcData);
            alert("orientation not reset - arrayCounter is: " + arrayCounter);
          } else {
            resetOrientation(URL.createObjectURL(fileToLoad), orientation, function(resetBase64Image) {
              imageList.push(resetBase64Image);
              alert("orientation reset - arrayCounter is: " + arrayCounter);
            });
          }
        });

      }

      //bubble_fn_1(imageList);
    })(fileToLoad);

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL -->

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="true" style="opacity: 100" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
```

Comment: I just tried this with dummy versions of `getOrientation` and `resetOrientation`, and it worked just fine. TBH I'm not sure I understand what your exact problem is, but I think it's to do with asynchronous order of execution. What I'd recommend for debugging is, instead of putting alerts everywhere, just call `console.log(imageList)` after `imageList.push(srcData);` and `imageList.push(resetBase64Image);`, and then check the console. That should give you proper updates what the actual contents of the list are as images are added to it.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, you should use the `onloadend` event instead of `onload`.

Comment: Thanks for replying back @MátéSafranka. I think I'm getting confused, it doesn't take a lot!
I swapped out all those alerts with console.log commands and it shows like this, I would expect this is the order things are running in?

arrayCounter: 0
filename: bike01.jpg

arrayCounter: 1
filename: bike02.jpg

arrayCounter: 2
filename: bike03.jpg

inside onload...  bike03.jpg
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST...

Now that image data is for the last image selected (I selected 3) - bike03.jpg

I thought it would give me 3 base64 image (that's actually what I need)

Comment: Ok I think I understand now, thank you. You're right, adding `console.log(ImageList);` after `imageList.push(srcData);` and `imageList.push(resetBase64Image);` does actually show the correct contents. I think I can't access it outisde of that function though, I think I can fix it. I'll come back soon.

Comment: If what confuses you is that it prints all filenames before it goes into the `onload` function, then yeah, that's just how asynchronous execution works. I wrote about it to someone else here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959875/9355798

Comment: Very helpful thanks very much, would you mind if I just ask ONE more question before I go.. how would one access that array (imageList) outside of the **getOrientation** function? I thought it would be `Return imageList` but I can't seem to get that to work. The imageList array is declared outside the function.

Comment: Well, the "elegant" solution would be to handle all this loading in Promises, but that would require a pretty drastic rewrite. A simpler solution you can use is to define a function, e.g. `onAllImagesLoaded()`, outside of `encodeImageFileAsURL()`. As the name implies, this would be the final step you call when all images are loaded, flipped, and ready for whatever you need to do with them. Then, inside your loadend callback, after you've pushed the image onto `imageList`, you can write `if (imageList.length == filesSelected.length) onAllImagesLoaded(imageList);`. Is it clear what I mean?

Comment: Yeh I think I understand that, had to read it a few times to take it in but I'm pretty sure I can do it. I won't ask anymore questions now as you've pretty much got me up and running again so thank you, you've been most helpful.

Comment: Hi @MátéSafranka I created another post about this, simply because we'd have loads of comments and I couldn't seem to put another code snippet in of changes I had made without editing this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005305/duplicating-base64-data