# Duplicating base64 data

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input, base64, onload

This is a follow up from the following link on stackoverflow
[Iterating through : Reader.OnLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999184/iterating-through-reader-onload)

which Máté Safranka kindly helped me with earlier.

I'm almost finished with it, does anyone know why in the function `function onAllImagesLoaded(imageList)` the line `console.log ("imageList: " + imageList);` is duplicating the image data all the time, that's what it's doing at the moment and I can't figure it out. If I select more than 1 file, the image data is the same for each one! Arggghh

Thank you

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

  var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
  var arrayCounter = 0;
  var imageList = [];

  for (arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < filesSelected.length; arrayCounter++) {

    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[arrayCounter];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      return function(e) {
        var srcData = e.target.result; // base64 data

        getOrientation(fileToLoad, function(orientation) {
        
          if (orientation == 1) {
            imageList.push(srcData);
            if (imageList.length == filesSelected.length) {
             //console.log ("imageList length: " + imageList.length);
              //console.log ("filesSelected length: " + filesSelected.length);
                onAllImagesLoaded(imageList);
           }
          }
          else {
            resetOrientation(URL.createObjectURL(fileToLoad), orientation, function(resetBase64Image) {
              imageList.push(resetBase64Image);
              if (imageList.length == filesSelected.length) {
             //console.log ("imageList length: " + imageList.length);
              //console.log ("filesSelected length: " + filesSelected.length);
                onAllImagesLoaded(imageList);
            }
            });
          }
          
        });
   }
      
    })(fileToLoad);

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
  }
}



function onAllImagesLoaded(imageList) {
 console.log ("imageList: " + imageList);
}


function resetOrientation(srcBase64, srcOrientation, callback) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    var width = img.width,
      height = img.height,
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
    if (4 < srcOrientation && srcOrientation < 9) {
      canvas.width = height;
      canvas.height = width;
    } else {
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
    }

    // transform context before drawing image
    switch (srcOrientation) {
      case 2:
        ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0);
        break;
      case 3:
        ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height);
        break;
      case 4:
        ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height);
        break;
      case 5:
        ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
      case 6:
        ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height, 0);
        break;
      case 7:
        ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height, width);
        break;
      case 8:
        ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    // draw image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // export base64
    callback(canvas.toDataURL());
  };

  img.src = srcBase64;
}



function getOrientation(file, callback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {

    var view = new DataView(e.target.result);
    if (view.getUint16(0, false) != 0xFFD8) {
      return callback(-2);
    }
    var length = view.byteLength,
      offset = 2;
    while (offset < length) {
      if (view.getUint16(offset + 2, false) <= 8) return callback(-1);
      var marker = view.getUint16(offset, false);
      offset += 2;
      if (marker == 0xFFE1) {
        if (view.getUint32(offset += 2, false) != 0x45786966) {
          return callback(-1);
        }

        var little = view.getUint16(offset += 6, false) == 0x4949;
        offset += view.getUint32(offset + 4, little);
        var tags = view.getUint16(offset, little);
        offset += 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < tags; i++) {
          if (view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12), little) == 0x0112) {
            return callback(view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12) + 8, little));
          }
        }
      } else if ((marker & 0xFF00) != 0xFF00) {
        break;
      } else {
        offset += view.getUint16(offset, false);
      }
    }
    return callback(-1);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL -->

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="true" style="opacity: 100" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
```

Comment: `fileLoadedEvent` you are not passing in a load event into your IIFE, you are passing in the file object. `getOrientation(fileToLoad` you should be using that argument here instead of `fileToLoad`, ie `getOrientation(fileLoadedEvent` but obviously you should rename it to reflect what it actually is

Comment: The problem is somewhere inside `resetOrientation()`. I just tested it a bunch of times, and found that it always tried to reset each image (maybe you should check `getOrientation` as well?), and the output was always the same. If I flipped the condition `if (orientation == 1)` so that it would always just add the image to `imageList`, the images were all different, as expected.

Comment: Yep, `getOrientation()` returned `-2` for all of my images. Something's definitely not right there.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, I obvioulsy need to look further into it. Problem for me is that I've reached my learning curve so to speak so things from this point become a tad difficult but I'll keep at it! I have just chaned what you suggested @PatrickEvans and that's good, will take a look at that getOrientation function next.

Answer (score 0):

`getOrientation()` returned `-2` for all of my images. Looking at the code, that happens when first two bytes of the image aren't 0xFFD8. Google tells me this particular byte sequence is called the "JPEG frame tag". I.e. `getOrientation()` is only compatible with JPEG images, whereas the ones I tried were all PNG. You'll need to find some way to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with getOrientation(). Because it's asynchronous it doesn't process the pics in order.

So you need to amend getOrientation() to return file as well as the exif value, like this...

```
...return callback(file, -2);
...return callback(file, -1);
...return callback(file, view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12) + 8, little));
etc
```

That way when it returns you can match the exif value with the file that went in.

Otherwise there's no way for your script to know & it will just use the data from the last file that went in for all files.