# React passed up array acting weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm facing a weird issue in my React-Project I just can't seem to figure out.

```
function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);


  const handleFileAdd = function(newFiles){
    console.log(newFiles);
    console.log([...files, ...newFiles])
    setFiles([...files, ...newFiles]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="main-child"><FileHandler addFiles = {(x) => {handleFileAdd(x)}} setFiles={setFiles} files={files} setSelected={setSelected} selected={selected}/></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Trough another component the addFiles function gets then further passed down to the FileDrop component.

```
    function FileDrop(props){

    const onDropFunction = function(files){
        var temp = [];

        files.forEach( (file) => {
            var reader= new FileReader();

            reader.onload = () => {
                const binaryStr = new TextDecoder().decode(reader.result);
                temp.push({"name": file.name, "format": file.type, "data": binaryStr});
                };

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
        props.addFile(temp);
        
    };

    return(
        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFunction} multiple={true}>
            {({getRootProps, getInputProps , isDragActive}) => (
                <section>
                <div id='drop-off-area' {...getRootProps()}>
                    <input {...getInputProps()} />
                    {isDragActive ? 
                    <p>Drop your file here :)</p> :
                    <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>}
                    <div id='drop-off-area-files'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </section>
            )}
        </Dropzone>
    );
}
```

When I print out the 'newFiles', which is a array of Objects, it prints out the normal array I passed up.
When I then print out the joined array below, it suddenly empty.
I just can't figure out, why this is happening..
Thanks in advance

I already tried different ways of concatenating and copying the array, but nothing helps..
Other functions, in which I update the files-array are working as expected.

Comment: Can you make a more complete [mcve] which demonstrates this behavior?  The specific behavior you're referring to does sound odd indeed, and could be an error in your debugging.

Comment: Looks like you call props.addFile before files are loaded. `reader.readAsArrayBuffer` is asynchronous method meaning that you should process the loaded file inside `reader.onload` callback

Comment: Consider to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485929/read-multiple-files-with-javascript-and-wait-for-result